# using sed to add the results of a grep to the 2nd line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I need to add 3 lines returned from a grep command to the 2nd line of a file.  I have the following somewhat working however getting sed to add the line to my file has been troubling.  Any help is appreciated.

```
TARGET=$(cat $EPH_DIR | grep -A2 "^$SAT")
```

returns:

```
O3B_M001    
1 00001U 001001   13134.54166667  .00000000  00000+0  00000+0 0 00018    
2     1   0.0399 359.0429 0028976 145.2061 239.3456  5.02804648    06
```

I need to add these lines to a file...I have this however it doesn't really work.

```
sed -i "2i/^/<"$TARGET"/" "$BASE_DIR/$FILENAME"
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$TARGET` should be inside the double quotes.

Comment: What do you mean by "add"? Do you mean you have to *append* these lines (as a single line?) to an existing line, or do you have to *insert* these lines after the first line of $BASE_DIR/$FILENAME?

Comment: Thomas- Yes, sorry.  Actually, I am appending this at the 2nd line.

Comment: Kevin-  Thanks.  I'll give it a whirl...:)

Answer (score 2):

awk is easier:

```
awk -v t="$TARGET" 'NR==2{print t}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TARGET=$(cat "$EPH_DIR" | grep -A2 "^$SAT" | sed -e 's/$/\\/' -e '$s/\\$//')
sed -i "2i\\
$TARGET
" "$BASE_DIR/$FILENAME"
```

The `sed` command in the `$(...)` line adds a backslash to the end of each line except the last (or, more precisely, adds one to the end of each line and then removes the backslash at the end of the last line).  The main `sed` command uses `2i` to insert the material in the `$TARGET` value before line 2 (use `2a` to place it after line 2).

*Tested.*

Comment: Thanks Jonathan- Worked perfectly...you rock! :)